# WMS layer is distorted

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms

My WMS layer(EPSG:3847) looks fine in GeoServer
[image]
However, it is distorted in browser:
[image]
I found someone hade the same problem([Openlayers and Geoserver: OSM/Google Maps and WMS Overlay](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17231/openlayers-and-geoserver-osm-google-maps-and-wms-overlay?rq=1))but I still couldn't solve the problem. I also tried to add code like

```
var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3847");
var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var lund_center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(13.2, 55.7).transform(
                geographic, mercator
```

and

```
map.setCente(lund_center, 10);
```

but the WMS layer is still distorted. 
I also tried this code but nothing's changed (EPSG3847 is not included in proj4.js, is that why the code didn't work?):

```
EPSG4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
EPSG3847  = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3847 ");

var option = {
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3847 "),
            displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
            };
```

How can I solve this problem? Any help please?
*the code I'm trying now are as follows, still,nothing changed：

```
    var lon = 12.1;
    var lat = 48.4;
    var zoom = 10;
    var map, vectors, controls;      
 var options = {
        controls: [],
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:3857'),
        displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'),
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(           
        -20037508, -20037508,20037508, 20037508.34),
        //modify parameter
        maxResolution: 5000,
        //modify parameter
        //setting zoom levels
        numZoomLevels:15,
        units: 'm',

    };

 function init(){

    var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    allOverlays: true
    });



    var roads_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Roads",
            "http://localhost:8090/geoserver/wms/wsNYCRoad", {
            projection: map.displayProjection,
            layers: 'vagar_alla',
            styles: '',
            srs:'EPSG:3006',                
            transparent:true,
            tiled: 'false',
            tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom
        },
        {
            buffer: 0,
            displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
            isBaseLayer: false,
            reproject: true
        });
        Proj4js.defs["EPSG:3006"] = "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";
        Proj4js.defs["EPSG:4326"] = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";
        var src = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:3006');
        var dst =  new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');
        Proj4js.transform(src, dst, roads_wms); 
        roads_wms.projection=dst;
```

Comment: This is correct behaviour. Going from degrees to meters will inevitably change the shape as sadly the earth is not flat :D.

Comment: @JohnBarça Thanks for your answer.So you are saying I don't need to do any transformation? Is there anyway I can display the layer in the browser as it is displayed in GeoServer?

Comment: I'm sorry I misread that as 3857. 3847 is a Swedish projection so you will need to add proj4js I imagine.

Comment: @JohnBarça as I said 3847 is not included in proj4js, so no use to add proj4js, besides there's no format for Proj4js.defs["EPSG:3847"]="" T_T

Comment: So why are you surprised that it looks different?

Comment: @JohnBarça so it's like I have to change the projection in GeoServer to the one that is included in proj4js, however it seems none of the swedish projections is included in proj4js.EPSG2400 is not included, but it do has a proj4js format, so I have to creat like epsg2400.js?

Comment: If you know the actual proj4 string, you can edit the epsg file proj uses and add it yourself.  Projections are ordered by epsg number in the file, so put it in the right place.  SpatialReference.Org seems to be missing the proj4 for this one http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3847/ but you could infer it from the WKT and the proj4 for another transverse Mercator projection.

Comment: @RussellatISCI changed it to epsg2400,then I add proj4.defs["EPSG:2400"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15.80827777777778 +k=1 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs"; and "var map = new OpenLayers.Map({projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:2400"),
displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:2400")...); now the layer cannot be displayed in the browser at all.

Comment: That doesn't quite match what I see in the WKT in the link I sent... and did you try just adding

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem:

First, re-project the wms layer in ArcMap to WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere(epsg3857). Then use this code:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
            maxScale: 1/5000,
            minScale: 1/500000,
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
            displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            div: "map",
            allOverlays: true
    });

var proj = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(1468582.90048,7501836.76895);
lonlat.transform(proj, map.getProjectionObject());
map.setCenter(lonlat, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't quite match what I see in the WKT in the link I sent... and did you try just adding (preferably with corrected lon_0, x_0, and y_0 from WKT mentioned in my comment)

```
# Swiss Transverse Mercator
<3847> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15.80827777777778 +k=1 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs  no_defs <>
```

to the epsg file?

Comment: Yes I did, but it didn't work. I also tried to reproject the wms layer in ArcMap, but still it is displayed as distorted in the browser.

Comment: and why as long as I add projection and displayProjection the layer disappeared from the browser completely？

Comment: I only know projections, not GeoServer.  I have C# code written in-house that uses proj (via DLLImport) and we've handled odd projectiouns by adding them to the epsg file as described.  Are you sure you edited the right file?  It's in the folder referenced by the PROJ_LIB environment variable.